# Ruby on Rails Find a String in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

please don't shout... I'm trying to run a search query to find the Firstname in the database, basically trying to find a specific user then show that user.

What works in the console is Client.where but I can't seem to get this to work in the controller.

```
irb(main):001:0>client = Client.where("name = 'Dusty'")
Client Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE (name = 'Dusty')
```

What I have is.

A View 'index.html.erb':

```
<%= form_for :find_it do |n| %>
   Name: <%= n.text_field :text, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %></br>
<%= n.submit "Find" %>
```

And a Controller Method in clients_controller.rb:

```
def find_it
  @post = Clients.all
  @post = Client.where("name = ", params[:find_it])
  @post = Client.find(params[:id])
end
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the form_for section correct? Because when I click it it throws me to the 'new' method.

Comment: Did you add the action on routes.rb ?

Comment: Yes, I have this entry in routes.rb match "/find_it" => "clients#find_it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off. Use hash-style conditions:

```
def find_it
  @post = Client.where(:name => params[:find_it])
  # @post = Client.find(params[:id]) # why is this line here? It overwrites previous results
end
```

Comment: Sergio Thank you for you're quick response.

Comment: When I click on the 'Submit' button I have in the form_for view section, I'm being redirected to create a new client in the database.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do that:

```
# with old hash syntax (all ruby versions)
@clients = Client.where(:name => params[:find_it])

# with new hash syntax (ruby 1.9)
@clients = Client.where(name: params[:find_it])

# with text query
@clients = Client.where('name = ?', params[:find_it])
```

All of them are equivalent.

Code `@post = Client.all` assigns variable `@post` with **all** clients from database and then you reassign it two times with completely different values. In the end your variable `@post` is assigned with `Client` record with id equals to `params[:id]` and this is what will you get in a view.

Also in general you don't have to use `all` method. Notice that:

```
Client.where(name: params[:find_it]).all.class
# => Array
Client.where(name: params[:find_it]).class
# => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

It means that you can query `ActiveRecord::Relation` with other querying methods i.e.

```
@clients = Client.where(name: params[:find_it])
@favourite_clients = @clients.where(favourite: true)
```

Rails will know what to do (it won't process `ActiveRecord::Relation` until it has to do something with it, i.e. while iterating result in a view), so you would want to add `all` only when you really need array in controller.

You should also consider using more meaningful variables names like `@clients` instead of `@post`.

When it comes to whole solution it should be more like:

```
# view
<%= form_for :find_it, :url => find_client_path do |n| %>
  Name: <%= n.text_field :text, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %></br>
  <%= n.submit "Find" %>
<% end %>
```

Take a look at `form_for` [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for). You can find out that your text is not `params[:find_it]`, but `params[:find_it][:text]`.

You have to provide `:url` option with path to your `find_it` action.

If you want to show results on index view, you can do it like:

```
# view
<%= form_for :find_it do |n| %>
  Name: <%= n.text_field :text, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %></br>
  <%= n.submit "Find" %>
<% end %>

# controller
def index
  @clients = Client.scoped
  @clients = @clients.where(:name => params[:find_it][:text]) if params[:find_it]
end
```

Comment: Thank you Lucas, I'm using the old hash syntax at them moment, however when i look at my 'rails s' output the query isn't run through the database. I only get a (0.2ms) BEGIN and a (0.1ms) ROLLBACK, then the 'new' page renders.

Comment: Do you show result in the view? Rails won't do anything with `ActiveRecord::Relation` until it has to, so probably you do not render a view or do not iterate through selected items.

Comment: Hi Lucas, below my Client.where statement I call a Render "show" statement, would that be sufficient?

Comment: I updated my post, take a look at it. If you want show action, why are you using `.where(:name => params[:find_it])`? It will give you collection.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for all the info. Still struggling. Will google a bit and see if I find something.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
@post = Client.where("name = ", params[:find_it])
```

with

```
@post = Client.where("name = ?", params[:find_it])
```

Comment: Thank you Shweta, Is the form_for section correct? Because when I click it it throws me to the 'new' method.

Comment: I changed the controller find_it method to look like the below.

    def find_it
    #@post = Client.where(:name => params[:find_it])
    @post = Client.where("name = ?", params[:find_it])
    render "show"
    end